# `bundle update` spins indefinitely in the Resolving Dependencies phase

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

After over 3 hours and thousands of dots, I killed it.

I then tried nuking Gemfile.lock, manually installing the latest Rails 3 gem (3.2.16), and running `DEBUG_RESOLVER=1 bundle install`.

Same deal, only this time I could watch while bundler flailed wildly.

I'm not sure how to debug the resulting trace.  If anybody has any suggestions based upon my Gemfile, I'd appreciate it:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem "unicorn" # app server
gem 'honeybadger' # exception notifier

# Memcached and Rack::Cache
gem 'memcachier'
gem 'dalli'

gem 'rails', '< 4.0'
gem 'acts_as_list'
# FIXME: Remove jquery loading elsewhere
gem 'jquery-rails', '<3.0.0' # The latter to avoid issue with Active Admin 0.6.0

# DB
gem "pg" # Postgres
gem 'foreigner' # FK constraints
gem 'immigrant' # FK constraints
gem 'mongoid' # MongoDB

# K/V store
gem "redis"

# Versioning
gem 'paper_trail'

# Analytics
gem 'mixpanel'

group :staging, :staging_v3, :production, :production_v3 do
  # Heroku - avoid deprecation warnings.  Grouped because it screws up logging in Dev.
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Auth
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-async'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

# Async
gem "delayed_job_active_record"
gem "daemons"

# Images
gem "rmagick", "2.13.2"

# Monitoring
gem "newrelic_rpm"

# Admin
gem "activeadmin"
gem "ckeditor" # WYSIWYG HTML editing
gem "just-datetime-picker"

# Uploads
gem "paperclip"
gem 'aws-sdk'

# Decoding/encoding HTML entities
gem 'htmlentities'

# List of countries
gem 'country-select'

# Convert integers to English words
gem "numbers_and_words"

# Surveys
gem 'survey-gizmo-ruby'

# Wizard flows
gem 'wicked'

# URI parsing
gem 'addressable'

# Generating link previews
gem 'embedly'

# User-friendly select input tag
gem 'select2-rails'

# Autocompletion
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

# PDF generation
gem 'shrimp', git: 'git://github.com/elyngved/shrimp.git'

# Browser detection
gem 'browser'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'thin' # appserver

  gem 'faker'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'acts_as_fu'

  gem 'factory_girl_rails'

  gem "highline"
  gem 'jasmine-rails'

  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda'

  # VCR
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'webmock', "< 1.10.0" # for VCR

  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'capybara-angular'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'

  gem "launchy"
  gem "Selenium"
  gem "selenium-client"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"

  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'rspec-mocks'
  gem 'webrat'

  gem 'spork'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
end

# Must be pulled out for local compilation
gem 'sass-rails'#,   '~> 3.2.3'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails'#, '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
gem 'jbuilder'
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of `DEBUG_RESOLVER=1 bundle install` (maybe as a link to a gist)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Gemfile` does not specify many version constraints, which gives Bundler a huge field of options to search through. You might be able to help it along by giving more specific version constraints for many of your gems. In particular, it's a good idea to specify an exact version of `rails`.